# Php string replace of values

Tags: php, string, str-replace

In opencart shop i have a product limit in category page, for example the default number of products per page.I setet up the maximul number to be 1000, but i wanna strig replace that number to "ALL".
Belo is the code for the string. `<?php echo $limits['text']; ?>`
I wanna string replace `$limits['text']` for the value 1000 to be ALL

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
        <?php foreach ($limits as $limits) { ?>
        <?php if ($limits['value'] == $limit) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo  $limits['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>"><?php echo  str_replace('1000', 'ALL', $limits['text']); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
```

This works but in the link of the page it sould be like this 
/index.php?route=product/category&path=142#/sort=p.sort_order/order=ASC/limit=1000
but is like this 
/index.php?route=product/category&path=142#/sort=p.sort_order/order=ASC/limit=All

In inspect element the code is generated corectly

```
<select>
                                <option value="http://diamanti.teamweb.ro/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=142&amp;limit=30" selected="selected">30</option>
                                            <option value="http://diamanti.teamweb.ro/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=142&amp;limit=90">90</option>
                                            <option value="http://diamanti.teamweb.ro/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=142&amp;limit=1000">All</option>
                              </select>
```

But when i click ALL , the link modifiecs not with the "value" But with the text...

Comment: i think looking for this `<?=($limits['text'] == '1000' ? 'All' : $limits['text'])?>`??

Comment: Can you be a bit more clearer ? What did you try ? is there any error message? Can't really see what you want us to do here.

Comment: I'm still not sure about what your actual question is, but I suggest using something other than "1000" to be your value for "all". That could bite you in the foot someday when you want to increase the maximum limit and you can't figure out why it's not working. Instead use something like "-1" or even the string "all".

Comment: As devpro said
`<option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo ($limits['text'] == '1000' ? 'All' : $limits['text']); ?></option>`

You could also change the `$limits['text'] >= '1000'` so in the future it will not break if the number does go above 1000

Comment: @Blinkydamo Assuming that's going to be in a loop, why use PHP to do that at all. Just add it to the HTML after the last iteration.